# can't get value from NSDictionary which expected to have NSNumber as output

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I have created a NSDictionary like following :

```
NSArray * alphabets = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d",@"e",@"f",@"g",@"h",@"i",@"j",@"k",@"l",@"m",@"n",@"o",@"p",@"q",@"r",@"s",@"t",@"u",@"v",@"w",@"x",@"y",@"z",nil];

    alphaToNum = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    numToAlpha = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for(NSString* character in alphabets)
    {

        [alphaToNum setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:index] forKey:character];
        [numToAlpha setObject:character forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:index]];
        index++;
    }
```

now I want to access to "numToAlpha" like following :

```
NSInteger code1;
NSNumber * nn = [numToAlpha objectForKey:code1];
```

and I'll get error whereas in manual for objectforkey it clearly said (id)objectforkey(id) which means anything!

Answer (score 2):

`NSInteger` is not an object. `id` refers to any *object* type. You need to use `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:code1]` as you are already doing in your code sample.